# How can I run an agent node and a collector node on a same machine using flume-node command?

Tags: flume

I'm trying to test aggregating logs using Flume.

Installed CDH3u3 (name node, secondary name node, job tracker, data node, task tracker) and Flume (flume, flume-master, and flume-node) on ubuntu machine `host1`. For Flume installtion I followed https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDHDOC/Flume+Installation .

I want to run flume master, collector node, and agent node on a same node. When I use plain `flume` command, I can run all three services successfully: ( reference: http://ankitasblogger.blogspot.com/2011/05/installing-flume-in-cluster-complete.html )

```
$ flume master
$ flume node -n flume-collector
$ flume node -n flume-agent
```

However, it is impossible to run two nodes using `flume-node`:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/flume-master start
$ sudo /etc/init.d/flume-node start
```

I can't give a node name to `flume-node` command, and it just creates a node named `host1.host.com`.

Should I use `flume` instead of `flume-master` and `flume-node` if I want multiple nodes on a same machine? I think `flume-master` and `flume-node` give more convenience because it informs the log path, while `flume` logs to stdout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to install two nodes on same machine.
You can configure the logic nodes on flume-master, they can work on different logic nodes, these nodes just on different ports.

The difference between collector and agent is what they do, not where they are, they all use flume-node.